# Remapping keyboard keys on SteamOS every time a new device is connected

Tags: linux, keyboard, steamos

I'm attempting the remap some keys for a specific keyboard on my Steam Deck running SteamOS. I've managed to prepare script that:

- Uses `xinput` to find ID of a specific keyboard.
- Exports the current layout via `xkbcomp`.
- Replaces selected key mappings in the exported file.
- Overrides the layout settings with `xkbcomp` utilizing the `-i` flag.

The script is working when ran locally via a terminal. However, the layout settings are reset every time the keyboard is disconnected or the device is restarted.

To automatically run the script when the keyboard is connected, I've added a `udev` rule that executes it on `add` events. The script is correctly executed when the keyboard is connected, but it's unable to access the X server:

```
Unable to connect to X server
```

I've tried running the script via `su - deck`, but the result is the same.

Is there a way to trigger a script relying on `xinput` when a new bluetooth device is connected, either with or without `udev`? Ideally, I'd prefer to avoid scripts that run continuously in the background and rely on events instead.